# Aborted Snapshot Isolation Transaction - Update 'parent' & Insert 'child'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given the following data model:

[image]

We run two separate transactions with 'Snapshot Isolation'.

Transaction #1: Insertion of 'Child'-records.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT

BEGIN TRAN
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

INSERT INTO [Snapshotsch].[dbo].[Child] ([Id], [Name], [ParentId])
VALUES (NEWID(), 'AAAA', 'A130AC13-F2E4-4ABD-8D5B-8DD33E472C58')

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

INSERT INTO [Snapshotsch].[dbo].[Child] ([Id], [Name], [ParentId])
VALUES (NEWID(), 'BBBB', 'A130AC13-F2E4-4ABD-8D5B-8DD33E472C58')

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

COMMIT TRAN
```

Transaction #2: Update of 'Parent'-record.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT

BEGIN TRAN
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

UPDATE [Snapshotsch].[dbo].[Parent]
SET [Name] = 'AAAAA'
WHERE [Id] = 'A130AC13-F2E4-4ABD-8D5B-8DD33E472C58'

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

COMMIT TRAN
```

When I run these transactions concurrently, one will fail with an error:

```
Msg 3960, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
Snapshot isolation transaction aborted due to update conflict. 
You cannot use snapshot isolation to access table 'dbo.Parent' 
directly or indirectly in database 'Snapshotsch' to update, 
delete, or insert the row that has been modified or deleted 
by another transaction. Retry the transaction or change the 
isolation level for the update/delete statement.
```

Is there anything we can do to make these transactions run concurrently succesfully? It is obvious to me that the conflict detection of snapshot isolation is causing this error but seeing as there isn't an actual conflict at hand here I'm wondering if we can remedy it with some kind of hint or setting.

Comment: The optimistic concurrency check for `SNAPSHOT` isolation is done on the row referenced by the foreign key rather than a specific column. In this case, the problem transaction contains only `INSERT` statements so you could use `READ_COMMITTED` instead.

Comment: Maybe! Could we actually step it up a notch by using `READ_UNCOMMITTED` instead? I can only imagine trouble with that decision when:
1. the 'Parent'-record its 'Id'-value changes;
2. the 'Parent'-record is deleted.

Neither case is applicable with our system.

Comment: What benefit do you expect with `READ_UNCOMMITTED` versus `READ_COMMITTED` in this case?

Comment: When using `READ_COMMITTED`, the 'Insert Child'-transaction will remain blocking until completion of the 'Update parent'-transaction. This is not the case when using `READ_UNCOMMITTED`. Seeing as we're neither deleting nor updating the 'Parent'-record its 'Id'-column I cannot see the benefits of using `READ_COMMITTED` over `READ_UNCOMMITTED` in this scenario.

Comment: The child table `INSERT` will still acquire a shared lock on the referenced parent table key in either `READ_COMMITTED` or `READ_UNCOMMITTED`. This will be blocked until the parent table `UPDATE` transaction commits and releases the exclusive lock on the same key.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was under the impression that there was no blocking transaction with `READ_UNCOMMITTED` but indeed there is. Then I suppose `READ_COMMITTED` is indeed the best option.

Comment: I agree `READ_COMMITTED` would be best. On a side, note `READ_UNCOMMITTED` can result in missed or duplicated rows during scans, not just reading uncommitted data, although that won't happen here.